# dmd can't infer type even when type is given

Tags: foreach, d, dmd, size-t, type-deduction

Here I want to lockstep iterate over two arrays of size_t

```
import std.stdio;
import std.range;
import std.exception;
import std.conv;

struct zip(R,Q)
if(isInputRange!(R) && isInputRange!(Q))
{
    R r;
    Q q;
    @property
    const auto front() {
        return tuple(r.front, q.front);
    }
    void popFront() {
        r.popFront();
        q.popFront();
    }
    @property
    const bool empty() {
        bool re = r.empty;
        enforce(re == q.empty);
        return re;
    }
}

void main() {
    size_t[] a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    size_t[] b = [2,3,4,5,6,7];
    foreach(size_t i, size_t j; zip!(size_t[],size_t[])(a,b)) {
        writeln(to!string(i) ~ " " ~ to!string(j));
    }
}
```

But this fails to compile with

```
src/Interpreter.d(30): Error: cannot infer argument types
```

However when I change the foreach line to use uint instead of size_t (I'm on a 32-bit laptop)

```
foreach(uint i, uint j; zip!(size_t[],size_t[])(a,b)) {
```

It compiles and runs just fine.  What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a bug. In v2.065.0 it doesn't work, but it does work in the latest git-head development version.

Comment: I'm pretty new to D.  I heard about it once before and I think posted a question on StackOverflow about getting set up, but I gave up on it.  Then I finally just picked up a book on it last week and this is the first thing I've written that uses templates.  Are D templates generally not yet stable?  Or was I just unlucky?

Comment: That worked.  I guess I'll have to use the dev version from now on.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you hit some bad luck here, most times when foreach(size_t a, something else;item), you want a to be an index into the array. That you wanted a size_t which was a tuple member it probably confused the compiler. There was some recent work on this area too because indexing ranges in foreach used to not work without a bit more code and that just recently got fixed.

Comment: Well, I ran into other problems.  Despite declaring every function and every class @safe, my program segfaulted.  I tried pulling the latest druntime from git, but it segfaults when trying to compile.  Is there a workaround that involves sticking with the stable version of dmd?